# map function in python , when mapping for x^3 for large numbers giving me negative values

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to map the function for x^3 for range of 1 to 10^5 , but it is returning negative values .

```
import numpy as np

import datetime

s= list(np.arange(1,10**4))

t1= datetime.datetime.now()

s1= (list(map(lambda x:x**3,s)))

s2= (list(map(lambda x:x**2,s)))

set1= set(s1)

set2= set(s2)

print(min(s1),min(s2), min(s))
```

my output is :

```
-2147398523 1 1
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce on Python 2 or 3. My output is `1 1 1` in either case.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo: It's OS-dependent - NumPy's default integer type is C `long`, which is 32-bit on Windows.

Comment: I wouldn't mix ordinary lists and Numpy values like this. Either `s = np.arange(1, 10**4)` or `s = list(range(1, 10**4))`. One is an array of Numpy (fixed-size) integer values, the other is a list of Python (arbitrary-size) `int` values.

Comment: @chepner, it worked with list , thank you . But still curious why it should be problem with numpy array ?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica , yes its an interger overflow problem , because of int32 , got solved with int64 , thanks

Comment: The array is what causes the list to be filled with fixed-precision integers rather than arbitrary-precision `int`s, leading to the overflow.